# Remove y axis of one plot in a multipanel "cowplot" graph but keep the plots the same size

Tags: r, plot, cowplot

I have plotted two plots with the same y-axis scale side-by-side, and aligned them using cowplot. I'd like to remove the y axis of the right-hand side plot but when I do this, this plot becomes wider than the left one (I would like the plots to be the same size). Does anyone know how I can remove the y axis of the right plot but keep the two plots the same size? Any help would be much appreciated. I can't use faceting due to the nature of the data. I can't share the actual data and don't know how to simulate any but I'm hoping this won't be needed for the question and I've shared as much code as I can. I'd also like to stick with cowplot if possible. Thank you.

```
    #code with y axis on both 
    library(ggplot2)
    library(cowplot)
p1<-ggplot(clins, aes(x = Clinician, y = slope, ymin = slope - 2 * se, ymax = slope + 2 * se)) + geom_point(color="blue") + geom_errorbar(colour="blue") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.16,1), breaks=c(-0.16, 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00), labels=c("", "0.00", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75", "1.00"), expand=c(0,0)) + theme(axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour=c("transparent", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black")), panel.border=element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA), text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12), panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y=element_line(size=.1, colour="black",linetype="dotted"), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", angle=60, hjust=1), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) + labs(y= "Slope")
p2<-ggplot(vigns, aes(x = Vignette, y = slope, ymin = slope - 2 * se, ymax = slope + 2 * se)) + geom_point(colour="red") + geom_errorbar(colour="red") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.16,1), breaks=c(-0.16, 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00), labels=c("", "0.00", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75", "1.00"), expand=c(0,0)) + theme(axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour=c("transparent", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black")), panel.border=element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA), text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12), panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y=element_line(size=.1, colour="black",linetype="dotted"), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", angle=20, hjust=1), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) + labs(y= "Slope")
plot1<- plot_grid(p1, p2, align = 'h')
title<- ggdraw() + draw_label("Slope Coefficients by Clinician and Vignette", fontface='bold', fontfamily='Times New Roman')
svg("Plot1.svg",width=10,height=4.00)
plot_grid(title, plot1, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1,1))
dev.off()

  #code with y axis removed for second plot
p3<-ggplot(vigns, aes(x = Vignette, y = slope, ymin = slope - 2 * se, ymax = slope + 2 * se)) + geom_point(colour="red") + geom_errorbar(colour="red", width=.15) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.16,1), breaks=c(-0.16, 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00), labels=c("", "0.00", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75", "1.00"), expand=c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), panel.border=element_rect(colour="black", fill=NA), text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12), panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y=element_line(size=.1, colour="black",linetype="dotted"), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", angle=45, hjust=1))
plot2<- plot_grid(p1, p3, align = 'h')
title<- ggdraw() + draw_label("Slope Coefficients by Clinician and Vignette", fontface='bold', fontfamily='Times New Roman')
svg("Plot2.svg",width=10,height=4.00)
plot_grid(title, plot2, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1,1))
dev.off()
```

[image: Plot1]
[image: Plot2]

Comment: Rather than `element_blank` you could try `element_text(colour="white")` for the axis title and labels, and `element_line(colour="white")` for the ticks.

Comment: Thank you@AndrewGustar this works but now there is quite a bit of white space between the two plots which is not ideal, do you know of a solution to this or another solution to the problem which won't create space between the plots?

Comment: You could perhaps stick with your first solution and add `coord_fixed(ratio=x)` to the plot - and play with `x` until it looks reasonable.  Or you could play with the `rel_widths` option in `plot_grid`.

Comment: Hmmm ok. I tried both of this but neither are giving the results I need. Thank you anyway. I have seen people using par and mar but not sure how to apply this to my code.

Comment: They are used for base R charts and won't work with ggplot.  As well as `cowplot`, `gridExtra` does something similar.